# git: lost my working directory after sparse-checkout, pull, merge conflict

Tags: git, pull, recovery, sparse-checkout

I have lost all project data in git from all branches and I'm unable to recover it.

I created three branches: `'master'`, `'distribution'` and `'remoteerp'` (All with same code and just backup) and checked-out to `remoteerp`, then I configured the sparse checkout config as true and updated `/.git/info/sparse-checkout` file to `/inoERP/inoerp/www/` and `/inoERP/inerp/inoerp-server`. Then, I pulled my fork-project from github like this:

```
git remote add -f githubinoerp [github_url_to_my_fork_repo]
git pull githubinoerp master
```

Which caused conflicts in License.txt and Copyright.txt and showed only these files in working directory. As I'm not able to resolve merge-conflicts (I am still studying git as beginner), I just tried to reset to old state using `git reset --hard` however it changed nothing accept saying something like `sparse-checkout has changed your working directory`. Checking out to other branches (like distribution and master) subsequently is also not showing the original files. i have tried git reset Head -- hard and git reset --hard on (after checking out) all branches but no use.

how can i recover my project to older state?

Comment: If you're still a beginner you should probably stay away from advanced features such as sparse checkouts.

Comment: Alas i could do that but i am experimenting with inoERP which has a different directory structure of dustribution (after installation) as compared to   its repo on github and i wanted to download and checkout only a subdirectory of repo which is actual code.

Answer (score 6):

You are still in the sparse checkout mode, that's why you don't see your files.

Run the commands:

```
git config core.sparseCheckout false
git read-tree --empty
git reset --hard
```

This should restore your checkout to full.

Comment: I am using the instructions here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository

and getting the error: Sparse checkout leaves no entry on working directory. 
That is exactly what i got earlier than loosing all files from my work directory earlier.
Note: My local directory is 'myerp' and my remote name is 'githubinoerp'
What is wrong / missing with those instructions? causing issues.

Comment: Here is screenshot of my screen: 
https://www.screencast.com/t/IuQc3gxU

Comment: This message means your patters did not match any of the file. Search for it here, there are plenty questions about it.

As far as I understand you no longer need sparce checkout. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to learn to **merge-conflicts**. 
Conflicts are very common on team projects, so It's something you probably will use in the future.

Here you have a very good manual to resolve conflicts: https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-using-the-command-line/

Anyway, you can **check** your previous status with something like that:

```
git checkout hash-commit
```

You can get the hash using `git log` (after "**commit**").

It's a very comfortable way to check in which part fail something.

Edit: You used `git reset --hard`, but maybe it was not the last commit the problem. You could use `git reset --hard hash_commit`. **You should not use this** if you didn't check the commit before, because you can't undo this.

Comment: not working even now, th working directory is still missing all project files; same situation as before. Screenshot: https://www.screencast.com/t/nc3PCgZ2LNnk